# Access Secondary Userstore via LDAP Service WSO2IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I see that WSO2IS capable of having multiple user store and it has embedded LDAP Server. My question is, whether it is possible to setup secondary user store using JDBC for example and then make it browse-able via WSO2IS LDAP Server on its default port (10389) ?

Thanks

Comment: umm, you cannot do that. you can see both user store inside wso2 web console

Comment: Thanks for you information. Actually my goal is to integrate multiple user store to be accessed as one service (such as LDAP). Wondering whether it can be accomplished.

Comment: check this out: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs